# Need help in connecting to mongo db through mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to connect my local mongo db instance to my QA mongodb through mongo-connector. Below is the command i have used to connect. But after hitting the command its thinking for few seconds and coming out. I'm not seeing any error. Am i making any mistake in connecting to target mongodb instance?

```
C:\Dev\mongodb\mongo-connector>mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t mongodb://username:password@dbhost:27017/dbname -d mongo_doc_manager --oplog-ts oplog.txt
Logging to mongo-connector.log.
```

Comment: add -v  to the end of the command to improve the verbosity, and u will see more longs that can help you recognizing the issue

Comment: what you can do also is open another bash instance and display logs in the console as they come from mongo-connecter with this command, `tail -f oplog.timestamp`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm first trying this in my windows environment before trying in my linux server. I'm still unsuccessful in my local windows envrionment.

Comment: i guess you should also consider : https://github.com/rwynn/monstache instead of mongo-connector as mongo-connector is not is support since long